# Скрыть / показать div по клику (со сменой текста)

Tags: html, jquery

Нужно реализовать блок, который показываеться и скрываеться по клику, с учетом смены внутреннего текста.
Наброски на jquery, блок выежает и прячется, текст "Больше" появляеться, но вот при открытие блока, текст "Больше" на "Меньше" не меняеться :(

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('#block').toggle('slow');
  });
});
$(function() {
  if ($('#block').is(':hidden')) {
    $('#button').html('Больше');
  } else {
    $('#buttom').html('Меньше');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block" style="display: none;">Содержимое</div>
<div id="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```js
$('#button').html('Больше');

$('#button').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var
    $this = $(this),
    content = $('#block');  
  
  
  if(!$this.hasClass('trigger')){
    $this.addClass('trigger');
    $this.html('Меньше');
    
    content.slideDown();
  } else {
    $this.removeClass('trigger');
    $this.html('Больше');
    
    content.slideUp();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block" style="display: none;">Содержимое</div>

<div id="button"></div>
```

Comment: слишком громоздко для подобной задачи

Comment: @Invision, я свой ответ предложила как вариант решения.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение**

HTML

```
<div id="block" style="display: none;">Содержимое</div>
<div id="button">Больше</div>
```

JS

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#block').slideToggle(function() {
        $(e.target).text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Меньше' : 'Больше');
      });
});
```

[Демо](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mENwdY)

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер. Как раз столкнулся с данной проблемой, с которой столкнулся flappy_
Просто хочу предоставить вам свой код, правда кому-то он может показаться громоздким и могут найти альтернативы попроще, но мне доработанный код помог доработать div по клику, когда их несколько, ибо с существующим кодом возможно, что могут открываться/закрываться сразу все div с данным классом (или id)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.button_header').html('Show More...');
    $('.button_header').on('click', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var
            $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('trigger'))
        {
            $this.addClass('trigger');
            $this.html('Hide');
            $this.toggleClass('r').siblings('.sitenews_text').slideToggle(600);
        }
        else
        {
            $this.removeClass('trigger');
            $this.html('Show More...')
            $this.toggleClass('r').siblings('.sitenews_text').slideToggle(600);
        }
    });
});
```

Я рискнул добавить вместо content toggleClass и .siblings, и начали открываться/закрываться только нужные мне div
Надеюсь, что был полезен

Comment: это не является ответом. Если Ваш случай чем-то отличается и вы не нашли нужного ответа, то воспользуйтесь [формой создания нового вопроса на странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и опубликуйте Ваш вопрос со всеми подробностями.